# Is there a way to make sub-projects inside projects in a repository on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, repository, project, repo

I wanted to create a repository of my mini projects and I don't really want to put them many separate repos of small projects. So I want to create a single repo called 'Mini Projects' and put my mini projects inside it. On doing some research I found that creating a repository ('Create Repository') was better suited for me rather than 'Create Project'.

Can this be done?
If yes, how? An example would be awesome.
If no, please suggest alternatives?

Comment: How do you define "project"? Nothing's preventing you from creating a repository containing each of your projects in a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [monorepos](https://monorepo.tools), it's not something that's required for what you want to achieve; you could just throw in all of your projects within a single git repository and call it a day. But monorepos provide efficient tooling to make this clean and scalable.